# How to upload files from a VS 2008 C# desktop application to a Windows server 2008/IIS 7

Tags: c#, .net, upload, desktop-application

I am wondering what is the best approach/methods/technology to implement a C# desktop application that can upload files to a server?

I was thinking of using a HttpWebRequest in the desktop application to send the files and then a webservice to handle the files on the server.
I need the server to check for user credentials and I need to know when a file has been uploaded.

I would like to know how I can approach this project - does anybody know how?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are thinking of using `HttpWebRequest` for up/downloads? There is a dedicated `FTP` protocol used specially for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but you can look into [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class for file uploads.